# Slack API - User details last updated date

Tags: slack-api

I am using https://api.slack.com/methods/users.lookupByEmail Slack Web API to get user details. Does the 'updated' property in the response represent the last updated date, if so what format is it in? Or is there any other way to get last updated date of user details/profile.

Comment: The `updated` field is in the epoch time. Online site can be used to convert epoch to human readable form. https://www.epochconverter.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `updated` property in the response represent the last updated date.
It is in **epoch time**,

you can find more details about epoch time here:

 https://www.epochconverter.com/

you can also get the same data by using `users.info` api method:

 https://api.slack.com/methods/users.info

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Suyash Gaur I tried it and it works. Marking this as the answer.